# How to adding custom message to loading map in grid? ExtJs 3.*

Tags: extjs

How to adding custom message to loading map in grid? ExtJs 3.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait..."});

// Editor grid Panel
var editorGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel
({
      store: store,
      cm: cm,
      renderTo: 'editor-grid',
      loadMask : mask
});
```

for more information :

[LoadMask](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.LoadMask)